# python Home work

Tags: python

> 1. define a string
> 2. define string's len
> 3. print true if the string len is even and the right half identical to the left half, else - print false.

I need to do it only in 3 lines and it has to work for every string len without change the condition in (3).

We didn't learn or loop yet. It supposed to be with slice.

please help.

---

i tried to do it:

```
some_string = "bb" 
str_len = len (some_string),str(a)
if str_len%2==0 and some_string[0:a/2]==some_string[a/2:0]: print "True"
else: print "False"
```

but something went wrong

Comment: so what have you tried that didn't worked?

Comment: You need to try it yourself first.

Comment: Read [this](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq).

Comment: and I also dont understang how can I do this in only 3 lines

Comment: Since I can't post this as an answer, take a look at [Conditional Expressions](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-308-conditional-expressions)

Comment: i did, but still didnt understand..

Comment: Here's a tip: `print 10 > 20`. I just output `False` without typing the text `False`.

Comment: tnx, but how do i give him order to check the 2 halfs?
how can i devide them for every len string?

Comment: @user1562379 try `strs[0:length/2]==strs[(length/2):]` to check the two halfs.

Comment: The modulus stuff seems unnecessary. If you compare the two sides of the string when it's of odd length, the parts will be unequal; you don't need to check if they can be equal length first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is almost fine, just a little improvement needed. You don't actually need to check for even length using `modulus(%)` operator, as the second condition will automatically take care of it.

So, Here's how your code would look: -

```
>>> def check_str(value):
        mid = len(value) / 2
        return True if value[:mid] == value[mid:] else False

>>> check_str("abab")
True
>>> check_str("abb")
False
>>> check_str("aaba")
False
```

Comment: I dont think you need the modulo stuff .... it should  be false automagically if it is not even length as the sides wont match

Comment: @JoranBeasley. Yeah already updated. Just tested it now only. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

use a [ternary operator](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
In [38]: def ans(x):

    strs=x           # line 1
    length=len(strs) # line 2 
    print True if length%2==0 and strs[0:length/2]==strs[length/2:] else False  ## line 3
   ....:     
   ....:     

In [42]: ans("bb")
True

In [43]: ans("bbb")
False

In [44]: ans("abcabc")
True

In [45]: ans("abcdabc")
False
```

Comment: @user1562379 your python version?